# Showing data with gridview a data provider in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I want to show all information which I have in a dataprovider, which is like this:

```
Array
(
[status] => 1
[data] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 6
        [nombre] => Carlos
        [apellidos] => Morales
        [telefono] => 55555
        [perfil] => Persona
    )

[documentos] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [iddocumento] => 3
                [ruta] => 2.jpg
                [nombre] => 2
                [tamano] => 94372
                [extension] => jpg
                [user_id] => 6
            )
  )
```

I can show perfectly with a gridview the information about data, but documentos it's impossible. How can I do that?.

I have this:

```
<?=GridView::widget([
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns' => [
          ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
          [
              'attribute' => 'nombre',
              'label' => 'Nombre de Persona'
          ],
          [
              'attribute' => 'apellidos',
              'label' => 'Apellidos'
          ],
          [
              'attribute' => 'telefono',
              'label' => 'Teléfono'
          ],
      ]
  ])?>
```

Is it possible?. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your **data** array one-dimensional and **documentos** array multi-dimensional. You have to reduce your **documentos** array into one dimensional array  with using arraymap function.

```
 $one_dimensional_array =  array_map('current' , $documentos_array)
```